# How to optimize percentage check and cols drop in large pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a sample pandas dataframe like as shown below. But **my real data is `40 million rows and 5200 columns`**

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
'readings' : ['READ_1','READ_2','READ_1','READ_3',np.nan,'READ_5',np.nan,'READ_8','READ_10','READ_12','READ_11','READ_14','READ_09','READ_08','READ_07'],
 'val' :[5,6,7,np.nan,np.nan,7,np.nan,12,13,56,32,13,45,43,46],
 })

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, when, count, col

mySchema = StructType([ StructField("subject_id", LongType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("readings", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("val", FloatType(), True)])

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema=mySchema)

spark_df.select([((count(when(isnan(c)|col(c).isNull(), c))/spark_df.count())*100).alias(c) for c in spark_df.columns]).show()
```

The above code helps me to get the `percentage of nulls/nan in each column`. But when I run the same on my real data, the code is been running for a long time but no output yet. **How do I optimize this search and drop the columns which has 80% of nulls/nan?** Below is my server config

[image]

**UPDATED SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: can you run `spark_df.summary('count')` to find non-null counts and then use spark_df.count() to calculate the rates of null/nan values?

Comment: @jxc - But this also takes time and no output yet. I thought pyspark is usually fast. Isn't this just a normal count function?

Comment: Yes, its the normal count function but by this way you are counting the data frame again and again.

Comment: It ran for 2 hr and 32 mins in my data. Is there any efficient approach that can yield quick results for my data?

Comment: @jxc - When I ran `spark_df.summary('count')`, I get only the above output (refer post). Is it expected? How can I subtract this with the count? Shouldn't I be expecting to see a `value`?

Comment: @SSMK, `df.summary()` only checks numeric and string columns (types like DateType, TimestampType, ArrayType etc are skipped. do be careful about this limitation). Also, the numbers are all StringType and you will need to cast them into `int`. the total nrows is `N=df.count()`. you can either do the final calculation in Pandas or just a Python `for` loop.