# How to drop columns and not rows using pandas axis equivalent in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
'readings' : ['READ_1','READ_2','READ_1','READ_3',np.nan,'READ_5',np.nan,'READ_8','READ_10','READ_12','READ_11','READ_14','READ_09','READ_08','READ_07'],
 'val' :[5,np.nan,7,np.nan,np.nan,7,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,46],
 })

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, when, count, col

mySchema = StructType([ StructField("subject_id", LongType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("readings", StringType(), True)\
                       ,StructField("val", FloatType(), True)])

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df,schema=mySchema)
```

What I would like to do is drop columns which has more than 80% pc of `NaN, NULL or 0` values?

I tried something like below but it doesn't work

```
spark_df = spark_df.dropna(axis = 'columns',how=any,thresh=12)
```

The above is possible in `pandas` but it doesn't work here. I get the below error and it isn't surprising

> TypeError: dropna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Please note that my real dataframe is `40 million and 3k columns`. I referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58533373/how-to-optimize-percentage-check-and-cols-drop-in-large-pyspark-dataframe) but it doesn't have an answer yet

Is there anything equivalent to this in pyspark?

I expect my output to be like as shown below with just 2 columns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subset` parameter in `dropna` method to specify the columns to look null values in.

To remove all columns with more than 80% null values:

```py
columns_to_drop = []
count_before = spark_df.count()

for column_name in spark_df.columns:
    temp_spark_df =  spark_df.dropna(subset=[column_name], how=any, thresh=12)
    count_after = temp_spark_df.count()

    if ((count_before-count_after)/count_before) > 0.8:
        columns_to_drop.append(column_name)


spark_df = spark_df.drop(*columns_to_drop)
```

Comment: Thanks will try. But unfortunately my dataframe is real huge upto 40 million and 3k columns. So thinking whether it would be fast. Anyway upvoted. Will try and update the answer soon. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use this function, it is the fastest it can get:

```
def drop_null_columns_spark(df, threshold=0):
    """
    This function drops all columns which contain null values with a threshold.
    :param df: A PySpark DataFrame
    :param threshold: Minimum number of nulls to consider dropping of column
    """
    null_counts = df.select([F.count(F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).collect()[0].asDict()
    to_drop = [k for k, v in null_counts.items() if v > threshold]
    df = df.drop(*to_drop)
    return df
```

Comment: Thanks will try. Upvoted. But I already tried similar appraoch. Wouldn't this take longer time for like 1300 columns?

Comment: @SSMK Count is an expensive operation but it is needed because you need a null count right. The collect is inexpensive because you've aggregated to one row.